# Outlook MailItem HTML Formatting Dropdown

Tags: c#, html, outlook

I am currently writing a C# script to send an email.

I am using the `mailitem.htmlbody` and my table is being formatted correctly.

However, when I added a dropdown to it, the dropdown doesn't work.

The HTML works, I am inclined to believe it is something with Outlook or C#.

```
private void sendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            if (dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                string recordOwner = dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                string[] recordOwner1;
                recordOwner1 = recordOwner.Split();
                Outlook.Application application = null;
                application = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)
                    application.CreateItemFromTemplate("PATH");
                mailItem.Subject ="Auditing Skype, Cell, VOIP, and Glance Logs";
                mailItem.To = recordOwner1[0] + "." + recordOwner1[1] + "@hbmncode.com";
                string htmlString = "<HTML><Body><p>BODY TEXT.</p></body>";
                string htmlTable = "<table runat=server id=Table1 border=1 class=style1><tr><td class=style2 colspan=1>Transaction Type</td><td class=style2 colspan=1>Number/Skype/Name</td><td class=style2>Total Transactions</td><td class=style2 rowspan=1>Outgoing</td><td class=style2>Incoming</td><td class=style2>Date/Time Most Recent Transaction</td><td class=style2>Category</td><td class=style2>Notes</td></tr>";
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
                {
                  string name;
                  int cnt = 0;
                  int cntIn = 0;
                  int cntOut = 0;
                  string now = "06/09/2015 10:08";
                  string dropDown = "<form><select><option style=display:none>Choose an item</option><option>Employee</option><option>Affiliate</option><option>Non-Affiliate</option></select></form>";
                  DateTime dateRecent = Convert.ToDateTime(now);
                  if (dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "Phone Call")
                  {
                      name = dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                      cnt = 0;
                      cntIn = 0;
                      cntOut = 0;
                      dateRecent = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString());
                      for (int j = 0; j < dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows.Count; j++)
                      {
                          if (name == dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows[j].Cells[8].Value.ToString())
                          {
                              cnt++;
                              if (dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows[j].Cells[9].Value.ToString() == "Incoming Call")
                              {
                                  cntIn++;
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  cntOut++;
                              }
                              if(Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows[j].Cells[10].Value.ToString()) > dateRecent)
                              {
                                  dateRecent = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows[j].Cells[10].Value.ToString());
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  else if (dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "VOIP Call")
                  {
                      name = dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                  }
                  else if (dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "Glance")
                  {
                      name = dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      name = dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows[i].Cells[14].Value.ToString();
                  }
                  if (htmlTable.Contains(name))
                  {
                      continue;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      htmlTable = htmlTable + ("<tr><td class=style2>" + dataGridTransactions.SelectedRows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "</td><td class=style2>" + name + "</td><td class=style2>"+cnt+"</td><td class=style2>"+cntOut+"</td><td class=style2>"+cntIn+"</td><td class=style2>"+dateRecent+"</td><td class=style2>"+dropDown+"</td><td class=style2></td></tr>");
                  }
             }

                mailItem.HTMLBody = htmlString+"<br /><br />"+htmlTable+"</table></HTML>";
                mailItem.Display(false);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a Record Owner to email.",
                                "Error!",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A well-known fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: So outlook doesn't support the select tag? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: As you understand not all features are supported.

Comment: I've done a lot of research and have not found a pure HTML dropdown that does not use select. Is there an alternative or is it just not possible?